# Не могу открыть Docker

Tags: docker

Установила десктопную версию Docker'a, при попытке открыть программу — всплывает такое окно. В чем заключается ошибка и как ее исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Включите в BIOS виртуализацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас должна быть включена "виртуализация" процессора. Включается она в настройках BIOS. Ищите строку **Intel Virtualization Technology** в настройках своего BIOS.

Изредка данная технология может называться сокращенно "Intel VT".